# Materialize CSS / Rails: Roboto font not loading, not all CSS being applied

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, fonts, materialize

Using Ruby on Rails and Materialize CSS, the Roboto font is not rendering.

Additionally, the button text is not being styled correctly, so it is not bold, and it is grey if I click on a button.

[image: A screenshot of a front page of a website. It is styled with Materialize CSS. The Roboto font is not being rendered correctly. It is replaced with another font.]

My layout:

**`application.html.erb`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

  <title><%= yield(:title) %></title>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

I am not able to figure this out. Can anyone please help me?

Things I have tried:

- Using the `materialize-sass` gem
- Loading the font manually
- Installing the font on my computer

Comment: Where did you set your font?
You need to create a font-face and then include it inside a css selector.

Comment: @siegy Materialize automatically sets fonts...

Comment: @siegy It's also supposed to make the button text white, but obviously that did not happen

Comment: Did you open up your inspector? is there any error?

Comment: @siegy I opened the inspector and there doesn't seem to be one

Answer (score 0):

### The solution

There were some CSS rules predefined within `scaffolds.css.scss` that was setting the font to Verdana. Removing them solved the problem.